# Почему нету UI интерфейса для добавления записи к тэгу таксономии?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Скрин]

Я так понимаю в правой части должна быть возможность выбрать таксономию, но там ничего нет

Но есть в свойствах поста, но это не удобно
[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блок таксономий в посте является метабоксом. Метабоксы на странице редактирования можно включать/выключать.

Нажмите на 3 точки справа в углу -> Options и отметьте галочкой нужную вам таксономию и все появится.